# unable to find airflow.cfg file in windows 10

Tags: airflow, docker-desktop

I have installed apache airflow using docker desktop for windows and able to create DAGs and running webserver without issue. Here my question is, am unable to find airflow.cfg file in my local machine.

I am new to Airflow and docker please help me to find this one.

Comment: If you installed Airflow and run it in a Docker container, then it is natural that `airflow.cfg` file is not on your local machine. It remains in the docker container.
You should consider following a Docker tutorial to get comfortable with Docker basics.